# Why EF(in code first model) can't create the database automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I follow the docs from Official documents.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MovieDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Above is my db connectionStrings in web.config.

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Model. Can anybody tell me why EF did't create DB automatically?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx See #4, "where's my data."

Comment: you have to run the code (where you at least open a context once) in order for the database to be created.

Comment: The ERROR is Local Database Runtime ERROR